# WebGL animation slows down TensorflowJS model inference

Tags: tensorflow, webgl, fabricjs, web-worker, tensorflow.js

I'm running a model in TensorflowJS, in a web worker, using the WebGL backend. The model is queried once every 64ms and does inference in around 50ms on average. On the frontend I'm running an animation using fabricJS. When I start the animation concurrently with model inferences, requests to the model slow down to about 7000ms per request. The animation is running using FabricJS with (I think) a WebGL backend.

Why does TensorflowJS slow down when running an animation at the same time? How an I get around this limitation?

Edit: I'm pretty sure it is because the TensorflowJS session cache is resetting

Comment: Tensorflow uses the GPU so I guess it can do less computation if the GPU is also used for canvas rendering. You could maybe do less inferences? Why would you need an inference every 64ms?

Comment: @Kokodoko because I'm analyzing data in realtime. So can't budge on that.

Comment: But you’ll have to budge somewhere, since the GPU apparently can’t handle both tasks at the same time at 60fps. Maybe slow down the fabric framerate? Don’t forget to test this out on other user’s devices too.